# When to make a user control using expression blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

So I am working on a new app and I am using Expression Blend (for the first time) to create the layout and styles etc. but I have a question about when I would want to create a user control.

I have a borer that I want to use as the background for lots of stuff, however it is really a border in a border - then we will drop whatever controls into it. I want to reuse this of course, what is the best way to do that. I am thinking I want to make it into a user control?

The problem is unlike a standard border - I can't just edit a style in a resource dictionary because like I said - it's a border in a border.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a UserControl example that allows for UIElement content:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace TestClean.UserControls
{
    [ContentProperty("Child")]
    public partial class CustomBorder : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Child", typeof(UIElement), typeof(CustomBorder), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
        public UIElement Child
        {
            get { return (UIElement)GetValue(ChildProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ChildProperty, value); }
        }

        public CustomBorder()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<UserControl x:Class="TestClean.UserControls.CustomBorder"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Name="control">
    <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Red" Background="Pink" Padding="5">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="LightBlue" Padding="5">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=control, Path=Child}" />
        </Border>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Usage example:

```
<uc:CustomBorder>
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum"/>
</uc:CustomBorder>
```

Looks like:

[image: Sreenshot]

Just modify the borders at will.

---

**Edit:** To actually answer the question and somewhat reiterate what i said in a comment to Tim's answer, UserControls are appropriate for this since they directly encapsulate the visual representation and allow for composition while not requiring much custom logic (in theory they can be very complex though and include a lot of logic). They are more lightweight and immediate than CustomControls.

In WPF controls (i.e. normal controls, including CustomControls which just inherit from them) are considered to be lookless, they normally provide a default template but their key aspect is their functionality, if you think of a `ComboBox` for example, it's a control which contains items, it should have one or no selected element and there should be a dropdown which displays the items and supports selection etc. It is the responsibility of the control to provide the necessary properties and methods which make up this functionality. Since this sometimes requires certain visual elements to exist controls can define [parts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.templatepartattribute.aspx) which represent the minimal interface to the front-end.

Have a look at the [Control Authoring overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx), it is more in-depth and probably explains a lot of things better than i can.

---

Also: The ultimate lightweight method is only using Templates:

```
<!-- You can use any resource dictionary, specifying it in App.xaml
     simply makes it usable all over the application. -->
<Application.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomBorderTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="Red" Background="Pink" Padding="5">
            <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="Blue" Background="LightBlue" Padding="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Application.Resources>
```

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource CustomBorderTemplate}">
    <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum"/>
</ContentControl>
```

This yields the same result as the UserControl.

Comment: Thanks - that worked easily - the only thing is I don't know how to tell Blend about it. I mean, I can manually type it in and it works i.e. xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Shared.UserControls;assembly=Shared" and then - <controls:MyPanel Grid.Row="1"/>. I will need to figure that out so it can be just drag and drop for the rest of the team...

Comment: Maybe you can find something on StackOverflow, otherwise that's material for a new question, i never really use designers so stuff like that normally does not concern me.

Comment: I expanded my answer by the way since i did not really answer your question at first.

Comment: That is really cool, but in this case your first example is actually better because we may end up adding some custom logic to the user control at some point so it is nice to have it all there.

Answer (score -1):

You'd probably be better off not making a `UserControl` and instead making a Custom Control that derives from `ContentControl` or something similar - I say this because you're planning on having it contain other controls and that's a lot easier to do with Custom Controls than `UserControl`s.

Comment: Why the downvote? I don't mind - always willing to learn when I'm wrong. Just curious.

Comment: Sorry about the late comment, i was trying to sort out an example first. UserControls are find for the described problem, you can compose them quite nicely and insert content as well. CustomControls are more for heavy functionality implementation which requires a lot of logic that needs to be encapsulated.

Comment: But isn't it true that you can't (at least not easily) use a UserControl as a ContentControl in XAML? And by that I mean having something like `<my:CustomControl><Button Content="Hello World" /></my:CustomControl>` ? It was my understanding that this scenario was a lot easier with Custom Controls, and it seemed like that was the scenario the original poster was going for.

Comment: That is quite a myth, i now have an example up.

Comment: Learn something new every day. I guess the "easier" part of that myth probably comes from having to define the Child property and the ContentProperty attribute yourself in UserControl (which some people, myself included, would probably fail to discover) whereas deriving from something that already had those pieces defined would give it to you straight away. Thanks for the clarification H.B., much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome, i tried working with the inherited `Content` property at first but it didn't work out, there are quite a lot of pitfalls in control-authoring.