# adding a custom user control to blend

Tags: wpf, xaml, expression-blend

I have a custom user control that I have created, in my "shared" project - it works great [(thanks to H.B.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099892/when-to-make-a-user-control-using-expression-blend) i.e. I go in the XAML and say

```
 xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Shared.UserControls;assembly=Shared"
```

Then I say (somewhere in the layout)

```
<controls:MyPanel Grid.Row="1"/>
```

All this is fine and when I open the project in blend I can see it rendered however it is shown with a little yellow icon and it keeps telling my I need to rebuild the project 
[image]

I tried that (and it does build) but the error doesn't go away, plus when I search for it it doesn't show up - which obviously means I can't drag and drop it onto the screen, what am I missing - why can't blend see this? any expression blend ninja's out there? Obviously blend knows about the assembly why won't it see the control? Is there some what to add it to the "Library"?

thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, is your Shared project in the same solution as wherever you're putting this code? Also, how are you referencing it? Project reference or assembly reference?

Comment: Yes it is in the same solution and when I created the reference I just right clicked (in VS) and clicked, selected "add ref" and then clicked the projects tab - which I am pretty sure is a projects ref unless I am going crazy. Thanks